# ADB command not recognined

Tags: java, android, environment-variables, adb

> 'adb' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
>   operable program or batch file.

When setting `ANDROID_SDK_ROOT` environment variable `adb` command is not recognized.

```
%ANDROID_SDK_ROOT%\platform-tools  // adb not working
```

BUT when setting `ANDROID_HOME` adb starts working again.

```
%ANDROID_HOME%\platform-tools    // adb starts working.
```

What is wrong here? because it always shows warning on **ANDROID_HOME** variable that its deprecated.

**UPDATE:**
Found Something Weird every time I restart my PC `adb` stops working. i have to save environment variable again to make it work.

Comment: Well, what do those two variables expand to on your system?

Comment: android SDK path.  `C:\Users\USERNAME\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk`

Answer (score 0):

**ANDROID_HOME**

Deprecated (in Android Studio), use ANDROID_SDK_ROOT instead.

**ANDROID_SDK_ROOT**

Installation directory of the Android SDK package.

```
Example: C:\AndroidSDK or ~/android-SDK/
```

**ANDROID_NDK_ROOT**
Installation directory of the Android NDK package. (WITHOUT ANY SPACE)

```
Example: C:\AndroidNDK or ~/android-ndk/
```

**ANDROID_SDK_HOME**
Location of SDK related data/user files.

```
Example: C:\Users\<USERNAME>\.android\ or ~/.android/
```

**ANDROID_EMULATOR_HOME**
Location of emulator-specific data files.

```
Example: C:\Users\<USERNAME>\.android\ or ~/.android/
```

**ANDROID_AVD_HOME**
Location of AVD-specific data files.

```
Example: C:\Users\<USERNAME>\.android\avd\ or ~/.android/avd/
```

**JDK_HOME and JAVA_HOME**
Installation directory of JDK (aka Java SDK) package.

Note: This is used to run Android Studio(and other Java-based applications). Actually, when you run Android Studio, it checks for JDK_HOME then JAVA_HOME environment variables to use.

Comment: I know about these updates and variables. in my case `android_sdk_root` not working with adb. but changing it to `android_home` adb starts working.

Comment: I think you are generating android build in ionic using cordova.?

Comment: Yes. but i also work with native development and React-Native. and in all these i want to use ADB for debugging.